# iOS View won't show label and image

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard, uistoryboard

I have storyboard where I have background set and on a top of a background I have weather information showing up. Even if my "weatherInfo" view is set to be on top it is still not showing up. I've added random values (labels and images are not loaded dynamically) it is still not showing up. Here is my settings:

[image]

Comment: Have you add constraint to your views? It seems like they are missing.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

- Press ctrl + clic & drag from this view to its superview (Named View in your case). You should see a blue arrow
- When you release your click, hold shift and add : Center horizontally & center vertically (don't forget to click add constraints at the bottom of the pop up)
- Run your app and you should see your view
- Finally, try other constraints to get familiar with Autolayout !

Good luck !

Comment: no this did not resolve the issue, it is still not showing up

Answer (score 0):

Your background might be loading in after your Weather Info view.  I'm going to assume that the Background is set to match the superview.  Try flipping the order of the views.  Have the WeatherView come after the Background.

Comment: I have tried that, in any case it will never show weatherInfo, background will always stay on top

Answer (score 0):

Please ensure that you have gave the bottom constraint w.r.t the view.
Else the view wouldn't show up